# помогите с логикой реализации аутентификации

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Подскажите как организовать аутентификацию пользователя без ввода пароля и логина , если пользователь зарегистрирован то отправить ему на почту ссылку по которой он перейдет и залогинится с использованием flask.

Comment: А какая разница, проверять логин-пароль или проверять длинный нечитаемый идентификатор, сгенерённый для этого юзера и отправленный ему в письме?

Comment: не могу понять логику,брать эмайл из куки и  генерировать токен и отправлять или создать в таблице сгенерированый ключ

Comment: В таблице юзеров к полю логина и полю пароля создаёте ещё одно поле - с идентификатором, который отошлёте юзеру. Вам надо что? проверить, есть ли запись в таблице по заданным критериям, и получить сведения из этой записи, необходимые для создания сессии. А сверять логин и пароль или же идентификатор - без разницы.

Comment: можно поподробней, создать поле в таблице юзеров с токеном и при регистрации записывать сгенерированый токен и отправлять в куках?

Comment: Вы не валите в одну кучу аутентификацию и сессию. Аутентификация никакого отношения ни к токенам, ни к кукам не имеет. Токен формируется и куки пишутся, когда аутентификация выполнена удачно.

Comment: А как мне тогда достать ид юзера и узнать что он зарегистрирован, мне нужно просто когда человек зарегистрирован, нажал кнопку которая бы перенаправила его на почту и там была бы уже ссылка для входа по которой он переходит и на сайте залогиненым был, как то так)

Comment: При создании юзера генери ему код - скажем, как GUID. По кнопке - создавай URL с этим GUID (или по кнопке генери новый GUID взамен старого и создавай ссылку) и отсылай. При входе по ссылке - извлекай GUID, ищи, чей он, и аутентифицируй, если нашёл.

Comment: как мне определить что за юзер если без кук не могу понять?

Comment: А вот когда юзер заполнил поля логина и пароля и жмакнул "Войти" - ты тоже без кук не можешь понять, что за юзер?

Comment: там через формы принимаю данные и сверяю , а когда юзер не зарегистрирован и ничего не вводит, при этом он не залогиненый , то я не представляю как взять его эмайл или ид кроме как не из сесии или отдельных куков

Comment: @Kirill подумайте над вопросом, откуда система узнает на какой email слать ссылку, если пользователь заходит с нового компьютера первый раз? Куки - пустые, сессий никаких нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грубо говоря, обычно процесс работает так:

1. каждая защищенная страница перенаправляет неаутентифицированных пользователей на страницу логина
2. на странице логина пользователь вводит логин и пароль
3. обработчик логина проверяет правильный ли логин и пароль.
4. Если правильный - записывает идентификатор пользователя в сессию. А идентификатор сессии передается в куки.
5. Для каждой защищенной страницы проверяем, чтоб был куки с идентификатором сессии, а в  сессии смотрим, чтоб был идентификатор пользователя.

Для логина без пароля через email можно сделать, например, так. Меняем некоторые шаги:

2. на странице логина просим ввести только email. Далее обработчик сгенерирует URL с токеном для логина и пошлет его почтой.
3. когда пользователь открывает URL из почты, то обработчик по токену установит идентификатор пользователя и далее продолжит, как и в предыдущем случае.

Сам токен можно хранить, скажем, в БД, привязав к пользователю. Но лучше и удобней воспользоваться JWT, в котором можно сразу передавать идентификатор пользователя и устанавливать время действия токена.

Comment: спасибо за ответ , но задача состоит в том что бы пользователь не вводил ни эмайлы ни логины, но принцип понял , буду покладывать куку с ид пользователя при первом входе дальше по инструкции

Comment: Если у вас в куки лежит id пользователя, то зачем слать email? Уже известно, что за пользователь выполнил запрос.

Comment: точно, спасибо за ответы, запутался в этом

Comment: *буду покладывать куку с ид пользователя при первом входе дальше по инструкции* Ага... юзер запрашиваь сцылку с компа, а открывает её на сматфоне... ищите куку...